# Predicates returning. Prolog

Tags: console, prolog

So I have the predicate which returns true several time.

```
% true returns several times and i need to press ';'
?- get_all_transformed_moves.
true ;
true ;
true.
```

Is the swi prolog have some method which can help me to run this predicate without typing';'?

```
% Wished version 
?- get_all_transformed_moves.
true.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
likes(prolog).
likes(haskell).
likes(erlang).

likes_something:-
    likes(_Something).
```

if now you ask:

```
?- likes_something.
```

you will get

```
true ;
true ;
true.
```

this happens because prolog finds three ways to satisfy the likes_something/0 predicate (with prolog, haskell and erlang) so it answers true for three times.

this isn't exactly a problem; at any time you can press  and prolog will stop trying to find answers (this is quite handy when there are a lot of results).

the same thing happens to your predicate: there are three solutions and by pressing ; you force prolog to find them all. as Rocha suggested you could use findall/3. For example, you could write:

```
likes_something:-
   findall(X, likes(X), _).
```

and this will return just one `yes`

however, it doesn't offer more information than the previous version; instead it hides the fact that there are 3 solutions and wastes time trying to find more while the answer wont change.
For that reason I think that you should use findall/3 if you actually want to **see** the results:

```
likes_all(L):-
   findall(X,likes(X),L).
```

of course, the decision of whether you need to see the results or not is up to you (or rather to the problem you are trying to solve :p)

another option is to use a cut: `!/0`
for example:

```
likes_something:-
   likes(_Something),
   !.
```

this will stop prolog from searching for more solutions and you will get just one true.
note however that cuts can be tricky.

All in all:
if you want prolog to search for all the answers (if you decide to put them in a list or you have side-effects in your predicates or if you just want it): use findall/3

if you don't want to have the option to search for more answers: use a cut (!/0)

else just press enter instead of ;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the findall/3 predicate:

findall(Object,Goal,List).
produces a list List of all the objects Object that satisfy the goal Goal. Often Object is simply a variable, in which case the query can be read as: Give me a list containing all the instantiations of Object which satisfy Goal.

I suppose that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the predicate to succeed at most once, then you can use once/1 provided with SWI.

In your example:

```
?- once(get_all_transformed_moves).
true.
```